# Очистка модулей

Tags: delphi

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу на Delphi. Подключаю некоторые модули. 
Но использую в них только 20 функций из 2000. Лень выуживать что-то, что нужно для этих функций, чтобы создать файл из 20 функций вместо 2000.
Существует ли программа, которая бы убирала из модуля всё, что не используется в проекте?
(И вообще возможно ли это сделать для общего случая?)

Спасибо!

Comment: Для общего случая так никто не делает. (И исполняемый файл раздувается на десятки мегабайт).

Comment: ничего не раздуется. Линковщик умеет выкидывать, то что не используется. В том числе и делфовский.

Comment: другое дело, если это целая иерархия классов. Здесь так просто класс не выбросишь. Плюс есть такая вещь, как RTTI, которая сильно затрудняет анализ (в делфи, можно вызвать метод по его имени, заданным строкой. и попробуй компилятору догадаться, что именно может, а что нет - вот он и оставляет. А функциями-процедурами просто. Там можно угадать)

А вот когда используются bpl, то бывают случаи, когда компилятор выбрасывает целые классы, так как их загружают "хитрым образом".

Comment: KoVadim, а вот если допустим не используется RTTI и есть некие классы. Допустим кучу свойств и методов я в классе не использую и кучу классов даже не использую. И допустим никто не использует их в иерархии вызова. То ведь спокойно можно убрать их. 
А линковщик этим занимается? 
Потому что грустно как-то... Подключил модуль Classes и размер файла увеличился в неимоверно сколько раз... И знаю, что можно ручками вытащить, то что надо... Но так лень. Когда вытаскивал, то размер файла уменьшался ровно на столько на сколько и должно быть... Поэтому кажется, что линковщик этим особо не увлекается.

Comment: > не используется RTTI 

тогда будет, но только если компилятору явно сообщить, что не будет использоваться. А так, подключение sysutils уже все портит.

Некоторые связи такие неявные, что не то, что линковщик, продвинутый специалист не всегда может определить.

Если Вы гонитесь за размером, тогда просто посмотрите правильные классы и библиотеки.  Когда то я использовал [kol & msk](http://kolmck.net/rindex.htm). Суть в том, что они предоставляют "зеркальные классы", то есть дубликаты, но хитро обрезанные. В результате код тот же, а размер сильно меньше.

Comment: Большое спасибо, KoVadim!

Comment: @KoVadim: Почему бы вот это и не запостить в качестве ответа? На тему "программы нет, потому что это не нужно" и далее ваш текст. Многие бы плюсанули и вопрос был бы с ответом

Answer (score 1):

*Перенос ответа из комментариев*

---

Ничего не раздуется. Линковщик умеет выкидывать, то что не используется. В том числе и делфовский.

Другое дело, если это целая иерархия классов. Здесь так просто класс не выбросишь. Плюс есть такая вещь, как RTTI, которая сильно затрудняет анализ (в делфи, можно вызвать метод по его имени, заданным строкой. и попробуй компилятору догадаться, что именно может, а что нет - вот он и оставляет. А функциями-процедурами просто. Там можно угадать) А вот когда используются bpl, то бывают случаи, когда компилятор выбрасывает целые классы, так как их загружают "хитрым образом".

Некоторые связи такие неявные, что не то, что линковщик, продвинутый специалист не всегда может определить. Если Вы гонитесь за размером, тогда просто посмотрите правильные классы и библиотеки. Когда то я использовал [kol & msk](http://kolmck.net/rindex.htm). Суть в том, что они предоставляют "зеркальные классы", то есть дубликаты, но хитро обрезанные. В результате код тот же, а размер сильно меньше.